# QTableView Displaying Boolean values

Tags: c++, qt, boolean

I have an sql table that I am trying to load with QT. One column of my table is for boolean values but when I run the program it displays 1 and 0 instead of True and False. How do I get it to display True and False without having to store a string field for "True" and "False"

```
comm->prepare("select * from animals");
comm->exec;
queryModel->setQuery(*comm);
ui->tableView-setModel(queryModel);
```

Comment: Have you considered using a `QItemDelegate` for the column in question, or overriding `::data` in the model?

Comment: What's `queryModel`? Is it a sub class of `QAbstractItemModel`? If yes, how does `data()` function of your model look like?